# Why I am getting dates also while using Month only picker [PrimeNG]

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I read the PrimeNG documentation. I opened this issue on github also ([here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8309)). But didn't receive any answer yet. I'm using `primeng` component i.e. `<p-calendar>` along with some other primeng components. Here is my code:

```
<p-overlayPanel #op>
    <div id="comp-render" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl>
        <div class="all-container">
            <p>Time selection</p><br>
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
                <p-calendar view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2018:2022" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="Year-to-date"></p-calendar>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Comparing</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <p-dropdown [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1" ></p-dropdown>
            <br><br>
            <div>
                <p-calendar view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2018:2022" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="Previous Year-to-date"></p-calendar>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

But Why I'm getting this:
[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

PS: Assume that no bootstrap is being applied.

I tried updating the `primeng` and `primeicons` version. Things worked but there are some style issues.

[image]

Comment: you just want year and month to be selected?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the value. It is `mm/yy` only. But why it is showing dates unnecessarily.

Comment: Which version of primeng are you using?

Comment: "primeng": "^5.2.7"

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.2.9

Comment: any console error after updating the package?

Comment: @ng-suhas. No . Console is clean. There are some warnings but I'm sure they are related to my project and not pimeng

Answer (score 1):

Version 5 of PrimeNG does not support this feature you are trying to add - The view that shows only months `view="month"`. When browsing through the documentation you have to make sure you are browsing the correct version.

Take a look here: [Primeng-5.2.7/Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/calendar)

The *month only* was implemented in [version 6](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/calendar), so your solution would be to update PrimeNG to that version. Since you mentioned that you are using Angular 6, it should be pretty straight forward.

Edit your `package.json` and change `primeng` to `6.1.6`

**NOTE:** You might need to add `primeicons` as well

```
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.9"
```

To do it smoothly, follow the [PrimeNG - Get Started](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/setup) section for `version 6`

Comment: This worked but still I'm getting some design related issues. I'm editing the question.

Comment: @Tanzeel What style issues? It looks exactly the same as from PrimeNG documentation.

Comment: Issues are as follows:
1. Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr are the only 4 months I'm getting.
2. Apr is out of the white box
3. Those left and right arrows are increasing and decreasing years instead of months

Comment: Please follow the Get Started guide for version 6, as well as the Calendar documentation for version 6. I tried it and it's working perfectly.

Comment: I tried the solution, I got month picker also, thanks for that but I am not getting style after upgrading. May you please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900995/why-im-not-getting-proper-styling-with-p-calendar-primeng/58901718#58901718

Answer (score 1):

Like Dino mentioned month picker is not available in Primeng-5.2.7. But if you want to do with 5.2.7 you can do it with a simple CSS trick where you can pick only the month and the year.

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep body .ui-datepicker.ui-widget .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This will display only the year and the month.

Demo => https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-calendar-jdcrjq

Comment: Thanks suhas. But this is not what I wanted. :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel Ok, then I think you have to update the package :)