# Why I'm not getting proper styling with p-calendar [PrimeNG]

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, primeng

I'm learning Angular. I'm working on a project. I decided to add a `<p-calendar>`component from `primeng`. I installed the packages also. The versions were:

```
"primeicons": "^2.0.0",
"primeng": "^5.2.7",
```

I was getting everything perfectly. See this:
[image]

But now when I want to get months only. I wanted to change it to month picker. After doing some research I came to know that month only picker is not available in `primeng: ^5.2.7`. So i upgraded to:

```
"primeicons": "^2.0.0",
"primeng": "6.1.6",
```

and I also added these attributes to `<p-calendar>` tag:

```
view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy"
```

Component is working fine. But Why I lost all the styling. Those circles and hover effects, etc. See this:

[image]
Honestly, I'm not very good at css and styling. Please help.

My **angular.json**:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

Is there any way to edit or overwrite the designs.

Comment: Why are you including *bootstrap.min.css* in your *angular.json*? Perhaps there is a conflict between *primeng.min.css* and bootstrap. Try removing bootstrap, or load it before the primeng css.

Comment: @R.Richards, Sir without `bootstrap.min.css` the widget is looking even more pathetic. With underlines like anchor tag and months running into each other. Please help.

Comment: Does it look any better if you load *bootstrap.min.css* **before** *primeng.min.css*?    Try moving bootstrap above primeng in the `styles` section of the *angular.json*.

Comment: @R.Richards. Didn't work. :-(

Comment: Which theme are you using ? And also can you confirm if all other element’s styling is ok ?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

## Try adding themes inside styles array:-

## angular.json

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
   "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss",
   "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
]
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But unfortunately it applied some other theme but not the one I'm looking for. I think its because of `omega` theme. :-)